# Use of while-else in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am implementing the following code

```
if (t1==1)
{
 digitalWrite(l1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(l2, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(l3, LOW);
 digitalWrite(l4, LOW);
 while(t2!=1)
 {

 digitalWrite(l1, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(l2, HIGH);
 t2 = digitalRead(IR2);
}

 digitalWrite(l1, LOW);
 digitalWrite(l2, LOW);

 delay(10);
```

}
  My question is that whether this would or wouldn't be accepted as while-else just as we use in python.

***My interpretation of the code :***
  The flow of control will enter the "if" loop if the condition is satisfied and execute the next 4 lines. Then the while loop shall execute till t2!=1. Once the value of t2 is equal to 1, the last two statements shall be executed.

***Please correct if wrong.Thanks***

Comment: You are right..

Comment: Why the `python` tag?

Comment: Thanks for the response @PatrickTrentin

Comment: Sorry for the error @kazemakase edited the question. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

If you replace the `digitalWrite` to be a `printf` and run it in a c or c++ compiler, you'll see the result:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t1 = 1;
    int t2 = 2; //Make this higher if you want to see the while loop run longer
    if (t1 == 1)
    {
        printf("l1, HIGH\n");
        printf("l2, HIGH\n");
        printf("l3, LOW\n");
        printf("l4, LOW\n");

        while(t2 != 1)
        {
            printf("l1, HIGH\n");
            printf("l2, HIGH\n");
            //t2 = digitalRead(IR2);
            t2 = t2 - 1; //Make t2 be one less each time the loop runs
        }

        printf("l1, LOW\n");
        printf("l2, LOW\n");

        //delay(10);
    }
}
```

Results in:

```
l1, HIGH
l2, HIGH
l3, LOW
l4, LOW
l1, HIGH
l2, HIGH
l1, LOW
l2, LOW
```

try it [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php).